# How to use custom Theano layers in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano

I have custom layers defined in Theano. I'd like to use them in my Keras model. How can I do this? Do these layers (defined as classes) in Theano have to follow a certain format?

I couldn't find any resource for this. It'd be very helpful if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure operations:**

If these layers are pure operations, you can use keras [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layers.

The idea is to create a function taking one tensor (or list of tensors) and do all the operations inside this function:

```
def customFunc(x):

    #tensor operations with the input tensor x   
    #you can use either keras.backend functions or theano functions    
    #paste the theano functions here

    #you can also attempt to call the theano layer here, passing x as input

    return result
```

Then you create a Lambda layer from this function:

```
model.add(Lambda(customFunc, output_shape=someShape))
```

**Layers with trainable weights:**

If the layers have trainable weights, though, you must create a [keras custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).

It's a class where you define the weights in the `build` method and perform the operations in the `call` method:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, yourOwnParameters, **kwargs):
        self.yourOwnParameters = yourOwnParameters
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=someKernelShape,
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)

        #because of self.add_weight call:
        #I'm not sure if you can use the theano layer unchanged

        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):

        #paste the theano operations here
        return resultFromOperationsWith(x)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return calculateSomeOutputShapeFromTheInputShape()
```